# Saber quantos elementos eu tenho em uma array no Arduino

Tags: c, array, arduino, lista

Tenho uma ARRAY de no máximo 100 linha por 2 colunas, que será preenchida por um usuário.

O meu programa reproduzirá a atividade do usuário depois.

O que eu quero saber é como saber quantas linhas foram preenchidas com dados. Existe algum comando do C para isso?

Comment: Não existe, tem que criar um algoritmo.

Comment: Se você postar um [mcve] da parte que já funciona, fica mais fácil da comunidade ajudar. Sem ver como o código está implementado, tudo é "chute".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O ideal é começar limpando qualquer tipo de valor dentro do array.

```
int x; // limpa os valores do array
for(x=0;x<100;x++){
    array[x][0] = 0;
    array[x][1] = 0;
}
```

Em seguida é feito o método para a inserção.

```
void array_insert(int *data, int **array){
    if(array[99][0] && array[99][1])
        return; //encerra caso o array esteja cheio

    int pos = 0;
    while(array[pos][0] && array[pos][1]) // procura uma posição vazia
        pos++;

    array[pos][0] = data[0]; // insere valor na posição livre do array
    array[pos][1] = data[1];
}
```

E a contagem:

```
int array_len(int **array){
    int x=0;
    while(array[x][0] && array[x][1])
        x++;

    return x;
}
```

> Obs.: Como você disse que estava trabalhando com um array **100*2**, os valores são ponteiros duplos para que se consiga acessar as posições sem erro.

Comment: Brumazzi DB, muito obrigado! acho que isso vai me ajudar. Com disse sou novato, e esses fragmentos de código serao muito úteis!

Comment: @AndreWahlbuhlGanzarolli Se uma resposta resolve o seu problema, você pode clicar no **v** ao lado da resposta para marcar sua pergunta como respondida.